# Add items to an array at a specific position

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
var arr = [];
```

and want add items either at the beginning or at the end of an array. I add the items in the MouseDown event and check if the Y value is lower or higher. The lower values(Y) should be added to the beginning and the higher values(Y) to the end.

So far this can be solved with Push() and Unshift() like this. The first value is at 10(Y), the second value is at 30(Y).

```
arr.push(y);

if (arr[arr.length-1] < arr[arr.length-2]) {
  arr.unshift("Apple");
} else if (arr[arr.length-1] > arr[arr.length-2]) {
  arr.push("Orange");
}
```

My problem is now when there is a value at the middle. For example when I have this:

```
First value is 10(Y)
Second value is 30(Y)
Third value is 20(Y)
```

The result should be Apple, Banana, Orange. But the result will Banane, Apple, Orange.

Comment: `Array.prototype.splice` ?

Comment: `splice` can be used to insert elements in the middle of an array

Comment: Yes, but how I can know where the last value be inserted?

Comment: What do you mean?  push adds it to the end, unshift puts it on the front, and splice puts it where ever you tell it to.  It's up to you to keep track of where it was inserted.

Comment: @JCss you can iterate the array and find where it should be inserted, then use `splice` to insert the element. or you can simply just `push` it to the array, and then use `Array.sort` to sort the array.

Comment: @r3wt I can't use Sort because the values should be in the order as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
const sortedIndex = (arr, n) => {
  const isDescending = arr[0] > arr[arr.length - 1];
  const index = arr.findIndex(el => (isDescending ? n >= el : n <= el));
  return index === -1 ? arr.length : index;
};

sortedIndex(arr, 20); // 1
sortedIndex([10, 30], 20); // 1
```

It'll find which index you want to insert the new value into.

Returns the lowest index at which value should be inserted into array in order to maintain its sort order.

Check if the array is sorted in descending order (loosely). Use Array.prototype.findIndex() to find the appropriate index where the element should be inserted.

https://30secondsofcode.org/?